# Width of text changing when adding qed, but only sometimes

Tags: floats

I have the following markup.

```
\newcommand{\tom}[1]{\to_{#1}}
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.333\textwidth}
$[1\ 3\ 5\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 4\ 6]\tom{1}$

$[3\ 1\ 5\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 4\ 6]\tom{2}$

$[4\ 5\ 1\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 3\ 6]\tom{3}$

$[5\ 7\ 4\ 1\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 3\ 6]\tom{4}$

$[7\ 8\ 5\ 4\ 1\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 3\ 6]\tom{5}$

$[8\ 9\ 6\ 7\ 2\ 4\ 10\ 1\ 3\ 5]\tom{6}$

$[9\ 10\ 7\ 8\ 4\ 6\ 2\ 1\ 3\ 5]\phantom{\tom{7}}$
%
%$\phantom{a}$
%
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.333\textwidth}
$[1\ 3\ 5\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 4\ 6]\tom{1}$

$[3\ 1\ 5\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 4\ 6]\tom{2}$

$[5\ 3\ 1\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 4\ 6]\tom{3}$

$[6\ 7\ 2\ 3\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 1\ 4\ 5]\tom{4}$

$[7\ 8\ 3\ 6\ 2\ 9\ 10\ 1\ 4\ 5]\tom{5}$

$[8\ 9\ 6\ 7\ 3\ 2\ 10\ 1\ 4\ 5]\tom{6}$

$[9\ 10\ 7\ 8\ 4\ 6\ 2\ 1\ 3\ 5]\phantom{\tom{7}}$
%
%$\phantom{a}$
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}%
\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.333\textwidth}
$[1\ 3\ 5\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 4\ 6]\tom{1}$

$[3\ 1\ 5\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 4\ 6]\tom{2}$

$[5\ 3\ 1\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 4\ 6]\tom{3}$

$[6\ 7\ 3\ 1\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 4\ 5]\tom{4}$

$[7\ 8\ 4\ 6\ 1\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 3\ 5]\tom{5}$

$[8\ 9\ 6\ 7\ 2\ 4\ 10\ 1\ 3\ 5]\tom{6}$

$[9\ 10\ 7\ 8\ 4\ 6\ 2\ 1\ 3\ 5]\phantom{\tom{7}}$
%
%$\phantom{a}$
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.333\textwidth}
$[1\ 3\ 5\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 4\ 6]\tom{1}$

$[2\ 3\ 5\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 1\ 4\ 6]\tom{2}$

$[3\ 5\ 2\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 1\ 4\ 6]\tom{3}$

$[5\ 7\ 3\ 2\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 1\ 4\ 6]\tom{4}$

$[7\ 8\ 5\ 3\ 2\ 9\ 10\ 1\ 4\ 6]\tom{5}$

$[8\ 9\ 6\ 7\ 3\ 2\ 10\ 1\ 4\ 5]\tom{6}$

$[9\ 10\ 7\ 8\ 4\ 6\ 2\ 1\ 3\ 5]\phantom{\tom{7}}$ \qed
%$\phantom{a}$
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

It comes up as

[image]

Notice the frustrating change in width in the last line. I want the lines to be uniform, with the qed on the right. This doesn't happen when I only do one figure (as I do elsewhere in the document). Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What's the reason for `subfigure`?

Comment: @egreg To get the text side by side.

Comment: Use `minipage`s for that. `subfigure`s are mainly used for graphics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This screams `tabular`!

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newcommand{\tom}[1]{\to_{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{@{} l @{\hspace{3em}} l @{}}
$[1\ 3\ 5\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 4\ 6]\tom{1}$ & $[1\ 3\ 5\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 4\ 6]\tom{1}$ \\

$[3\ 1\ 5\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 4\ 6]\tom{2}$ & $[3\ 1\ 5\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 4\ 6]\tom{2}$ \\

$[4\ 5\ 1\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 3\ 6]\tom{3}$ & $[5\ 3\ 1\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 4\ 6]\tom{3}$ \\

$[5\ 7\ 4\ 1\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 3\ 6]\tom{4}$ & $[6\ 7\ 2\ 3\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 1\ 4\ 5]\tom{4}$ \\

$[7\ 8\ 5\ 4\ 1\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 3\ 6]\tom{5}$ & $[7\ 8\ 3\ 6\ 2\ 9\ 10\ 1\ 4\ 5]\tom{5}$ \\

$[8\ 9\ 6\ 7\ 2\ 4\ 10\ 1\ 3\ 5]\tom{6}$ & $[8\ 9\ 6\ 7\ 3\ 2\ 10\ 1\ 4\ 5]\tom{6}$ \\

$[9\ 10\ 7\ 8\ 4\ 6\ 2\ 1\ 3\ 5]$        & $[9\ 10\ 7\ 8\ 4\ 6\ 2\ 1\ 3\ 5]$ \\[2ex]

$[1\ 3\ 5\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 4\ 6]\tom{1}$ & $[1\ 3\ 5\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 4\ 6]\tom{1}$ \\

$[3\ 1\ 5\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 4\ 6]\tom{2}$ & $[2\ 3\ 5\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 1\ 4\ 6]\tom{2}$ \\

$[5\ 3\ 1\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 4\ 6]\tom{3}$ & $[3\ 5\ 2\ 7\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 1\ 4\ 6]\tom{3}$ \\

$[6\ 7\ 3\ 1\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 4\ 5]\tom{4}$ & $[5\ 7\ 3\ 2\ 8\ 9\ 10\ 1\ 4\ 6]\tom{4}$ \\

$[7\ 8\ 4\ 6\ 1\ 9\ 10\ 2\ 3\ 5]\tom{5}$ & $[7\ 8\ 5\ 3\ 2\ 9\ 10\ 1\ 4\ 6]\tom{5}$ \\

$[8\ 9\ 6\ 7\ 2\ 4\ 10\ 1\ 3\ 5]\tom{6}$ & $[8\ 9\ 6\ 7\ 3\ 2\ 10\ 1\ 4\ 5]\tom{6}$ \\

$[9\ 10\ 7\ 8\ 4\ 6\ 2\ 1\ 3\ 5]$        & $[9\ 10\ 7\ 8\ 4\ 6\ 2\ 1\ 3\ 5]\hfill$ \qedsymbol
\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]